# Cross-correlation only for part of the matrix

Tags: matlab, cross-correlation

I have two matrices (about 6000x6000 each) and I wish to find the offset of one from the other by using cross-correlation. I know that the maximum offset is at most by 100 cells so I wish to better optimize my code, but xcorr2 doesn't have an option to limit the number of offsets to calculate for.

Any ideas on how to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

Efficient correlation implementations commonly involve using the ifft/fft & some padding. With those implementations, it is not possible to limit computation to only a subset of the cross correlation. 201 out of 11999 might be at the point where a literal computation of the cross correlation might be worth